# Referentially transparent functions in Java

Tags: java

I'm learning about referential transparency in Java. How would I make the following code referentially transparent, so that both `first` and `second` have the same value?

```java
int first = numberList.remove(1) + numberList.remove(2); 

int second = numberList.remove(2) + numberList.remove(1);
```

Comment: A modifyable list ist per definition not referentially transparent, as the values, size (and position of values) must change during the lists lifecycle. Expecially the remove operation changes the list itself. As the structure changes, so do the positions of the elements. To make at least this one access 'referentially transparent', you'd first read the values you care for, and then remove them from the list. In other words, I'd wrap this in a method, and then read (and remove) the correct indice.

Answer (score 4):

Only [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) can be [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency).

Referentially Transparent function consistently produces the same result given the same input, no matter where and when it’s invoked.

Additionally, [Java 8 In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/java-8-in-action) tells you, that:

> A function is referentially transparent if it always returns the same result value when called with the same argument value. The method String.replace is referentially transparent because "raoul".replace('r', 'R') will always produce the same result.

Therefore, if you remove something from your `numberList`, you have a side-effect, and therefore, your `remove(..)` can not be referentially transparent.

As a more general observation, no side-effect functions can be referentially transparent.